# jquery ajax url path issues

Tags: jquery, ajax, path, form-submit

After doing several tests, I believe I have a path issue because everything else works besides the `submit()`. I checked the values and they are not empty. After going through many answers here on SO about the issue, none solved my problem. I'm wondering what can I do to make it work?

This is the structure of my project.

```
- includes
--footer.php
-user
--home.php
--js
---service.js
--queries
---request.php
```

home.php

```
include(__DIR__.'/../includes/footer.php');
```

footer.php

```
<script src="js/service.js"></script>
```

service.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.socialbutton').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
  $(".socialmediaform").submit(
                       $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType : 'json',
                        url: 'queries/request.php',
                        data:socialvalues,
                        success: function(data)
                {
                 console.log(data);
               //display successs message
               $(".servicedetails").append(successmsg);

                }
            })
          );
});
  });
```

Comment: Inspect your code in  (chrome/firefox) inspector  and check you network tab for ajax request, you may be able to find where the issue is and which file its sending the request to.

Comment: @Bee: Thanks. I was able to solve all my problems with your suggestion :-)